# Swift: Index out of range error for a table view while using firebase

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating an app just to learn the language mostly. basically I am trying to make an app that allows you to bet fake money on which `CSGO` team will win. So right now I am at the part of the app that allows a user to create a bet. then the user can see all of the bets he can then accept another users bet. I had all this working before, but I noticed a bug so I decided to fix it. The problem is now it crashes.

I need the app to go to a different screen where it allows you to make a bet on a team. then you click the box and set how much you want to bet on that specific team. Then when you click the submit `Button` at the bottom, it will upload the users information and the bet information to a `Firebase Database`. then it will go back to the previous screen that shows all of the bets that have not been filled yet. so his should too.

the problem is when I use `POPView` controller to go back to the previous view controller that shows the bets it gives me an index out of range error for the table view. the weird thing is if I move the method `getBetsFor` to `viewDidLoad` instead of view will appear then it works just fine. The problem with that is it will glitch and it won't show the bet that the user just made.

I know my code is horrific I have tried to put some of it into `MVC` format, but without further ado here is my code.

the code below is the code that gets the bets from the `Firebase Database` then puts that data into an array of objects then displays the objects onto the `TableView`

```
  //
//  BetView.swift
//  EDraft
//
//  Created by Devin Tripp on 3/20/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Devin Tripp. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Foundation
import Firebase


class BetView: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var teamOne: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var teamTwo: UILabel!
    let datRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference(fromURL: "https://edraft-77b47.firebaseio.com/")


    var userMoney = String()

    let getData = GatherData()

    var testies: String?

    var teamTOne = String()
    var teamTTwo = String()

    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds

    let navBar: UINavigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 60, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 50))
    var navItem = UINavigationItem(title: "Money: ")


    let doneItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.add, target: nil, action: #selector(sayHello(sender:)))


    let backItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.done, target: nil, action: #selector(goBack(sender:)))


    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.getData.betObjects.removeAll()
        self.getData.getBetsFor(completion: { (result) in
            if result == true {
                //show the spinning wheel thing
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            } else {
                // error
            }

        })
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.addSubview(navBar)
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = .none

        navItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneItem
        navItem.leftBarButtonItem = backItem
        navBar.setItems([navItem], animated: false)

        teamOne.text = teamTOne
        teamTwo.text = teamTTwo


        /*
        getData.getBetsFor(completion: { (result) in
            if result == true {




                self.tableView.reloadData()
            } else {

            }

        })
        */

        getData.getMoneyFromUser(username: self.getData.userName, completion: { (money) in

            if money == true {
                let usermoney = String(self.getData.userMoney)
                //update the UI
                self.navItem.title = "$" + usermoney
                print(self.getData.userMoney)
            } else {
                print("no money found")
            }



        })

    }




    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldUpdateFocusIn context: UITableViewFocusUpdateContext) -> Bool {
        return true
    }




    func updateBet(_ index: Int, completion: @escaping (_ something: Bool) -> Void) {
        let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
        datRef.child("User").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            // Get user value
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let username = value?["username"] as? String
            self.getData.userName = username!
            // ...


            self.datRef.child("Bets").observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
                //
                // this is the unique identifier of the bet.  eg, -Kfx81GvUxoHpmmMwJ9P
                guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyHashable] else {
                    print("failed to get dictionary from Bets.\(self.getData.userName)")
                    return
                }
                let values = ["OpposingUsername": self.getData.userName,"Show": "no"]
                //var val = self.getData.betObjects[index]
                //val.opposingUserName = self.getData.userName
            self.datRef.child("Bets").child(self.getData.tieBetToUser[index]).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                    let anothaValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                    let user = anothaValue?["Username"] as? String

                    if user == self.getData.userName {
                        // let the user know he cannot bet his own bet
                        completion(false)
                    } else {
                        self.datRef.child("Bets").child(self.getData.tieBetToUser[index]).updateChildValues(values)
                        completion(true)
                    }


                })



            })


        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }


    }

    func getOpoosingUserNames(_ username: String,_ index: Int, completion: @escaping (_ result: Bool) -> Void ) {
        let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
        datRef.child("User").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            // Get user value
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let username = value?["username"] as? String ?? ""


            self.datRef.child("Bets").child(self.getData.tieBetToUser[index]).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                let thisValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                if let thisUserName = thisValue?["Username"] as? String {

                    self.getData.opposingUserName  = thisUserName
                    completion(true)


                } else {
                    completion(false)
                }

            })
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }




    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //if makeEmpty == true {
        //    return 0
        //} else {
        print(self.getData.betObjects.count)
            return self.getData.betObjects.count
        //}
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellB", for: indexPath) as! CellB
        print(self.getData.betObjects[indexPath.row].userName)
        cell.userNameLabel?.text = getData.betObjects[indexPath.row].userName
        cell.amountOfBet?.text = getData.betObjects[indexPath.row].betAmount


        return cell

    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Accept Bet", message: "Match the bet of " + getData.amountBets[indexPath.row], preferredStyle: .alert)

        let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
            print("Ok button tapped")
        })

        let yesButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
            // let them know to wait a second or the bet won't go through
            var waitController = UIAlertController(title: "Please Wait", message: "Your bet is being processed", preferredStyle: .alert)

            self.present(waitController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            //take away the usersMoney
            self.takeAwayMoney(self.getData.amountBets[indexPath.row],index: indexPath.row, completion: { (result) in

                if result == true {
                    self.updateBet(indexPath.row, completion: { (result) in


                        if result == true {
                            self.getOpoosingUserNames(self.getData.userName, indexPath.row, completion: { (anothaResult) in

                                if anothaResult == true {
                                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                                        let successController = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: "You have made a bet with " + self.getData.opposingUserName, preferredStyle: .alert)
                                        let okButt = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
                                        successController.addAction(okButt)
                                        self.present(successController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                                        //lastly delete the opposing UserName

                                        let pathIndex = IndexPath(item: indexPath.row, section: 0)
                                        self.getData.betObjects.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                                        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [pathIndex], with: .fade)
                                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                                        print("Second")
                                    })

                                    self.getData.getMoneyFromUser(username: self.getData.userName, completion: { (money) in

                                        if money == true {
                                            self.userMoney = String(self.getData.userMoney)
                                            //update the UI
                                            self.navItem.title = "$" + self.userMoney



                                            print(self.userMoney)
                                        } else {
                                            print("no money found")
                                        }



                                    })
                                } else {

                                }
                                //wait for the first view to load in case it uploads to fast


                            })

                        } else {
                            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                                let cannotBet = UIAlertController(title: "Failed", message: "You cannot bet with yourself dummy", preferredStyle: .alert)
                                let okButt = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
                                cannotBet.addAction(okButt)
                                self.present(cannotBet, animated: true, completion: nil)
                            })
                        }


                    })



                } else {
                    // user doesn't have money
                    //display a alert that lets the user know hes broke
                    print("this should print once")
                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                        let brokeController = UIAlertController(title: "Failed", message: "Reason: You don't have enough money!", preferredStyle: .alert)
                        let okButt = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
                        brokeController.addAction(okButt)
                        self.present(brokeController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    })
                }
                var getResult = ""
                print("You have taken away the users money")

                    print("you made it this far almost there")
                    //let delayInSeconds = 3.0 // 1
                    //DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delayInSeconds) { // 2
            })


        return
        })

        alertController.addAction(okButton)
        alertController.addAction(yesButton)
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete) {
            self.getData.betObjects.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        }
    }


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        //let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        //var DestViewController : addBets = segue.destination as! addBets
        //DestViewController.teamOne = self.teamOne.text!
        //DestViewController.teamOne = self.teamTTwo

        if segue.identifier == "gotobetview" {
            if let destination = segue.destination as? addBets {

                destination.teamOne = self.teamOne.text!
                destination.teamTwo = self.teamTwo.text!
            }
        }




    }

    func takeAwayMoney(_ howMuch: String, index: Int, completion: @escaping (Bool)-> ()) -> Void{
        if let notMuch = Int(howMuch) {

            let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

            datRef.child("User").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                // Get user value
                let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                let money = value?["money"] as? String ?? ""

                //convert money to int
                if let conMoney = Int(money) {
                    var conMoreMoney = conMoney
                    if conMoreMoney < notMuch {

                        print(" You don't have enough money")
                        completion(false)
                        return
                    } else {
                        conMoreMoney -= notMuch
                        let values = ["money": String(conMoreMoney)]

                        //update the users money
                        self.datRef.child("User").child(userID!).updateChildValues(values)
                        completion(true)
                    }

                }
                // ...
            }) { (error) in
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }

    func getUserName() -> String {
        let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
        var useruser: String!
        datRef.child("User").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            // Get user value
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let username = value?["username"] as? String ?? ""

            self.getData.userName = username
            useruser = username

            // ...
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        return useruser
    }




    func sayHello(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let userInput = self.teamOne.text

        var userInputArray: [String] = []
        userInputArray.append(self.teamOne.text!)
        userInputArray.append(self.teamTwo.text!)
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotobetview", sender: userInputArray)





        //let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        //let homeView = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "addBets")
        //self.present(homeView, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func goBack(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let backView = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabview")
        self.present(backView, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Since I cannot post anymore code I will update the project on github and post a link here.

https://github.com/devintrippprojects/EDraft

if you download the project you can always create your own account you will start out with 100 dollars or you could use the main testing account the email is
k@k.com
and the password is 
kkkkkk

I will post how the database looks and how the app looks tomorrow thanks have a good night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded and ran your project.

Seems like the issue here is you should reload the tableView when you remove all the data source.

change this:

```
    self.getData.betObjects.removeAll()
    self.getData.getBetsFor(completion: { (result) in
        if result == true {
            //show the spinning wheel thing
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        } else {
            // error
        }

    })
```

to this:

```
    self.getData.betObjects.removeAll()
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    self.getData.getBetsFor(completion: { (result) in
        if result == true {
            //show the spinning wheel thing
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        } else {
            // error
        }

    })
```

With an extra line:

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: LOL that one line of code fixed the whole thing. Is there some website that can explain table view in more detail, I mostly get it, but stuff like this is crazy to me.

Comment: For general usage, I would recommend Ray Wenderlich's tutorial, but for this kind of sneaky things, sadly I guess only from experiences you can learn :(

Comment: also there is another bug that I can't wrap my head around I am pretty sure it has something to do with deleting the cells. sometimes and it is very random when it does it, but lets say you have three bets on the app the first bet is 10 the second is 20 and the third is 30 sometimes when you click on the bet that says 20 it will say match the bet of 10 and if you click on the 30 bet it will say match bet of 20. it only happens if you have already clicked on another bet and made a bet with them.

Comment: Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (10) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (15), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). and here is the enormous error you get

Comment: wait I think I fixed it I think I just needed to update the data in the table view from the database after someone makes a bet I was just deleting the row

Comment: Sorry I must feel like a bother by now mister Daniel, but If I could relay just one more question to you. I am basically doing this whole thing to strengthen my understanding of the swift language and programming in general, but I must know how much knowledge should I acquire(in years, or months, or mastery or intermediate knowledge) about the language before seeking job opportunities in programming in swift. Since that is the main goal.

Comment: From what I have observed, most of the company looking for an ios developer wouldn't only require the understanding of swift. You might need to know some utilities that work with swift, like Firebase, for example. Things can get way complicated then only know how to write swift code. I suggest you look at some of the job posts that you are interested in and start learning what knowledges they require you to know about.

Comment: The best would be you starting your own project which uses those utilities to show off your understanding.